# MPI_Isend not sending message immediately on MPICH v3.3.2

Tags: c, mpi, mpich

I'm writing a program for parallel computation of matrix multiplication, and I'm using the `MPI_Isend` function for non-blocking communication. Here's the main parallelization logic ::

- The master node is sending most of the work to different workers.
- Then it's doing part of the work itself. It expects that the workers—in the meantime—have started receiving their work and working on it.
- It waits for the workers to complete their work, by calling `MPI_Wait` and then `MPI_Recv`.

But, in reality, the workers receive their messages only when the master node calls `MPI_Wait`; so when the master node is doing its share of work the other nodes are sitting still. Why is this happening?

```c
#include "helpers.h"
#include <mpi.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int m = atoi(argv[1]);
    int n = atoi(argv[2]);
    int p = atoi(argv[3]);
    double start, elapsed;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int world_size, world_rank, name_len;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);
    printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n", processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

    float *A = malloc(m * n * sizeof(float));
    float *B = malloc(n * p * sizeof(float));
    float *C = malloc(m * p * sizeof(float));
    float *C_serial = malloc(m * p * sizeof(float));

    if (world_rank == 0) {
        randarr(m*n, A);
    } else if (world_rank == 1) {
        randarr(n*p, B);
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    start = MPI_Wtime();

    // Serial multiplication
    if (!world_rank) {
        Multiply_serial(A, B, C_serial, m, n, p);
        elapsed = MPI_Wtime() - start;
        printf("[*] Serial multiplication: %f seconds\n", elapsed);
    }

    // Parallel multiplication
    int mpart = m / world_size;
    MPI_Request request_ids[(world_size-1)*2];
    float *Apart = malloc(mpart * n * sizeof(float));
    float *Cpart = malloc(mpart * p * sizeof(float));

    // Master node
    if (!world_rank) {
        for (int i = 1; i < world_size; ++i) {
            MPI_Isend(&A[i*mpart*n], mpart*n, MPI_FLOAT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request_ids[(i-1)*2]);
            MPI_Isend(B, n*p, MPI_FLOAT, i, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request_ids[(i-1)*2 + 1]);
        }
        printf("[*] Started sending: %f seconds\n", MPI_Wtime() - start);
        // Master node's share of multiplication
        for (int i = 0; i < mpart; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < p; ++j) {
                C[i*p + j] = 0.0;
                for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                    C[i*p + j] += + A[i*n + k] * B[k*p + j];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("[*] Multiplied: %f seconds\n", MPI_Wtime() - start);
        MPI_Waitall((world_size-1)*2, request_ids, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        printf("[*] Sending completed: %f seconds\n", MPI_Wtime() - start);
        for (int i = 1; i < world_size; ++i) {
            MPI_Recv(&C[i*mpart*p], mpart*p, MPI_FLOAT, i, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        }

        elapsed = MPI_Wtime() - start;
        printf("[*] Parallel multiplication: %f seconds\n", elapsed);

        int correct = IsEqual(C, C_serial, m, p);
        printf("[*] Parallel correctness: %d\n", correct);
    }

    // Worker nodes 
    if (world_rank) {
        MPI_Recv(Apart, mpart*n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_Recv(B, n*p, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("[*] I'm worker, got work: %f seconds\n", MPI_Wtime() - start);

        for (int i = 0; i < mpart; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < p; ++j) {
                Cpart[i*p + j] = 0.0;
                for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                    Cpart[i*p + j] += + Apart[i*n + k] * B[k*p + j];
                }
            }
        }
        MPI_Send(Cpart, mpart*p, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

And here's a sample run of the program ::

```
sumit@HAL9000:~/Coding/parallel/parallel-distributed-assignments/A2$ time make mpinb
mpicc mpib.c -o mpib
mpicc mpinb.c -o mpinb
mpirun -n 4 ./mpinb 6000 32 6000
Hello world from processor HAL9000, rank 0 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor HAL9000, rank 1 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor HAL9000, rank 2 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor HAL9000, rank 3 out of 4 processors
[*] Serial multiplication: 4.700643 seconds
[*] Started sending: 4.700674 seconds
[*] Multiplied: 5.790390 seconds
[*] I'm worker, got work: 5.790726 seconds
[*] I'm worker, got work: 5.790901 seconds
[*] Sending completed: 5.790974 seconds
[*] I'm worker, got work: 5.791019 seconds
[*] Parallel multiplication: 6.920345 seconds
[*] Parallel correctness: 1

real    0m7.175s
user    0m27.699s
sys 0m0.479s
```

Comment: Your MPI implementation does not feature a progress thread, at least with the interconnect you are using.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet can you expand more upon this, or link to any resource? Also, I'm using MPICH v3 and running everything locally, so the interconnect is inter-process communication. Can you guide me towards some resource so that I can enable progress thread for MPICH?

Comment: I just tried the same code with OpenMPI instead of MPICH and it worked as expected. So yeah, MPICH doesn't have the proper progress thread implementation. Strange, given that supposedly it's the most popular and widely used MPI implementation.

Comment: out of curiosity, have you tried `MPI_Init_thead(..., MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, ...)` instead of `MPI_Init(...)` ? I am not familiar with MPICH internals, but that might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run it several times and did it behave the same ?

Try to tell the proc "rank = 0" to do a significant pause (of 10seconds maybe ?) pause just before the MPI_Waitall call. Because I'm not sure that this isn't working as you want. I think it could be just because the communication process is longer than the 3 for-loops execution, so that the workers finish their work after the proc "rank = 0".

PS: I think too that 2 of your printf messages are not the same in your code and in the exec ("Just sent" and "Sending done" seem to be "Started sending" and "Sending completed" of your code ?)

Comment: The communication process isn't longer than the 3 for-loops, I'm sure of that. Cause I have another implementation of this program which uses the blocking call, `MPI_Send`, and that runs twice as faster than this one.  

And you're right, I edited the `printf` messages in my code but didn't post the updated output. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Like I said in a comment to the question, the code is working as expected with OpenMPI. So it's an implementation problem with MPICH, seemingly it doesn't implement progress thread.